# apache Ivy authentication with artifactory

Tags: java, ivy, artifactory

I have shared repository in artifactory which requires authentication in order to resolve/retrieve dependencies.

For some reason Ivy is not able to authenticate.

my ivysettings.xml:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="main" />
  <credentials host="localhost" realm="Artifactory Realm" username="admin" passwd="password" />
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="main">
      <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" root="http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo" />
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

log file:

```
try to get credentials for: Authenticate Artifactory@localhost
authentication: k='Authenticate Artifactory@localhost' c='null'
HTTP response status: 401 url=https://localhost/artifactory/repo... the rest of the log file...
```

Artifacotry is configured to authenticate against ldap/active directory

Answer (score 1):

in my configuration realm="Artifactory Realm" was wrong. It should be: realm="Authenticate Artifactory"

Comment: Weird. I could get it working only with `Artifactory Realm` as mentioned in the [Jfrog docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Working+with+Ivy)